# application.properties file not being read

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to run an application on spring boot,i have mentioned server.port as 8081 but my application still runs on 8080.In fact it is not applying anything that i have mentioned on application.properties.
My application.properties file is:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://admin:admin@cluster0.r0sdgoq.mongodb.net/test
spring.data.mongodb.database=Cluster0
logging.file.name=filename.log
server.error.include-message = always
server.port=8081
library.url=http://localhost:8082/library/
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name=my-application
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=localhost:9300
spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=myGroup
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer

spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
```

but in the console it says its running on 8080

```
2022-11-23 16:53:33.413  INFO 11380 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
```

I initially thought i was running the wrong project but it is the same project.i tried giving different ports but it still runs on 8080.I even deleted the application.properties file and created it again but it still run on 8080

Comment: What is your folder structure? Where exactly is application.properties located?

Comment: It is in src\main\resources

Comment: How did you create the project? Is your application using an active profile? Cut the redundancy in the application properties and post a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: only the 'server.port' property is important from the pov of this question

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the directory on which your application.properties file is located. It is supposed to be under
**src\main\resources**

Comment: yes it is in src\main\resources

Answer (score 0):

Can you access the `application.properties` inside your application, outside of Spring Boot? E.G.:

```
try (InputStream stream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application.properties")) {
    System.out.println(new String(stream.readAllBytes()));
}
```

If you can this points to a configuration issue in Spring Boot.

If you can't, this suggests a project configuration issue - e.g. `resources` not specified in Maven for example.